# Why does OpenMP Nested SIMD Operation Crash in Debug Compilation

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, compilation, openmp

I'm working on an C++ project compiled with `icpc` which is parallelized using OpenMP5.

I had a bug causing my program to crash when compiling in debug mode, and run fine when compiling in release mode. After some debugging I found that the problem was two consecutive SIMD operations. A short example:

```
# pragma omp parallel
{
// .. do stuff ..
#pragma omp simd safelen(1)
  for (auto ind1 : indices1) {
    for (auto ind2 : indices2) {
      foo(ind1, ind2);
    }
  }
}

void foo(auto ind1, auto ind2) {
//  .. do stuff ..
  #pragma omp simd aligned(arr:64)
  for (int i : indices) {
    auto k = arr[i]
    if (k) {
        k = arr[i] + 1;
// .. do more stuff ..
    }
  }
}
```

Running in release mode, everything was fine, and in debug mode, I got segmentation fault in the line `auto k = arr[i]`. Replacing the first `#pragma omp simd safelen(1)` by `#pragma omp for` fixed that.

Thus, my question is not how to solve the problem, but what actually happened here? I think I understood vaguely what happened, but I still cannot understand why it worked fine in release mode..

I tried printing the values of `k` using `std::cout << k << std::endl` and got weird behaviors - sometime it printed 0 (i.e., null ptr, which is fine behavior in my program), and sometimes it printed nothing and even didn't get to the `std::endl`, i.e., I saw the consecutive print in the same line. I'm not sure if this is related and how exactly prints to the standard output work in parallel operations..

Thanks in advance!

**Edit #1**
Using `objdump -d my_objfile.o | grep vm` revelared that the number of SIMD operations didn't change as a result of my modification (`pragma omp simd -> pragram omp for`). This makes me think that I'm just "covering" for another "real" bug here. I'm also using `std::atomic`s around the code, the the `fetch_add` method, if that has something to do with anything.

Comment: I'm not very skilled in simd usage in OpenMP, but nested SIMD looks basically weird to me. Plus, your outer simd would normally require `foo` to be declared as simd capable.

Comment: I agree that nested SIMD doesn't make sense, there's definitely a bug\miswrite in my code. My question is just trying to understand if there's a deeper bug "underneath", and in general understand what happened here.. I discovered some more stuff, see in my edit.